# "find" function in C++ is giving different results while associating it with variables and "cout"

Tags: c++, cout

Code 1 : -

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name = "For all the times";
    cout << "Line 6 output :  " << name.find("ball",0) << endl;
    int num = name.find("ball",0);
    cout << "Line 8 output :  " << num;
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
[Running] cd "h:\C\" && g++ new.cpp -o new && "h:\C\"new
Line 6 output :  18446744073709551615
Line 8 output :  -1
[Done] exited with code=0 in 8.008 seconds
```

I wonder why line 6,8 gave me different outputs. I was expecting "-1" from both the lines.
However when I tried "all" instead of "ball" in the same code, this is the output.

```
[Running] cd "h:\C\" && g++ new.cpp -o new && "h:\C\"new
Line 6 output :  4
Line 8 output :  4
[Done] exited with code=0 in 9.88 seconds
```

Unlike the above case, here, both line 6,8 gave the same output.
Does the negative value -1, which is the output in the 1st case has something to do with it ? or is something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Please post your code/errors/output as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.  We also can't copy the text from images, which stops us from being able to debug your code, i.e., help you.

Comment: `find` returns `size_t` which is unsigned. At `int num = name.find` you are assigning that to a singed int.

Comment: Compile with warnings, you should get at least one.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the same number represented as two different types.  `std::string::find` will return `std::string::npos` if no string is found.  `std::string::npos` is an unsigned integer with the value of `-1`.  Since unsigned integer are never negative that value wraps around to the maximal value the unsigned integer can hold, which for 64 bits is `18446744073709551616`.  When you initialize an `int` with that value since it is a signed integer it can express negative numbers so you see `-1` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about types (an important part of C++)

The return type of `std::string::find()` is `std::size_t`  See: [doc](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

The `std::size_t` is an [unsigned integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) (i.e. no negative numbers). So this code:

```
cout << "Line 6 output :  " << name.find("ball",0) << endl;
```

Will never generate a negative number.
Hence you get the output:

```
Line 6 output :  18446744073709551615
Line 6 output :  4
```

The second bit of code. Has an interesting conversion.

```
// Here you are converting from a `std::size_t` into an `int`
// The compiler is happy to do this.
// Not sure it is totally legal (I forget the exact place in the standatd)
// But it is so common I would be surprised if it returned anything other than -1.
int num = name.find("ball",0);
```

So why does `18446744073709551615` convert to `-1`. Have you looked at the bit pattern for that number.

```
 18446744073709551615  => 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Notice all the bits are set. When you out that in an integer variable. This has the same value as -1 in 2's complement representation.

Thus this line:

```
cout << "Line 8 output :  " << num;
```

Will generated a signed number. And you will get:

```
Line 8 output :  -1
Line 8 output :  4
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because `find` returns a `size_t` not an `int`. So in the line
`int num = name.find("ball",0);`
you are making an implicit cast to `int`.
he code below will give the same result:

```
std::string name = "For all the times";
size_t num = name.find("ball", 0);
std::cout << num << std::endl;
std::cout << name.find("ball", 0);
```

See the documentation of `std::string::find` at [C++ reference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Please note that if the string is not found the return value is `std::string::npos` which casted to an `int` gives `-1`